# Unable to connect to localhost port running docker image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a basic HelloWorld express app on my localhost using docker.

**Docker version:** `Docker version 19.03.13`

**Project structure:**

```
my-project
  src
    index.js
Dockerfile
package.json
package-lock.json
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
# Use small base image with nodejs 10
FROM node:10.13-alpine

# set current work dir
WORKDIR /src

# Copy package.json, packge-lock.json into current dir
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

# install dependencies
RUN npm install --production

# copy sources
COPY ./src .

# open default port
EXPOSE 3000

# Run app
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "knative-serving-helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple hello world sample in Node",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Hello world received a request.');
  res.send(`Hello world!\n`);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Hello world listening on port', port);
});
```

Here are the commands I'm running:

```
>> docker build --tag hello-world:1.0 .   // BUILD IMAGE AND GET ID
>> docker run IMAGE_ID                    // RUN CONTAINER WITH IMAGE_ID
```

Image seems to build just fine:

[image]

And this is the result after I run the image:

[image]

But this is what I get when I hit `localhost:3000`

[image]

I'm very new to Docker. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish your port 3000.

`docker run -p 3000:3000 IMAGE_ID`

Just exposing the port is not enough it needs to be mapped on the host's port too.

Comment: Thanks. Can I add this "publish" info to the `Dockerfile` somehow? Or does it always have to be in the `docker run` command?

Comment: @cbdeveloper: no. In general I don't even use `EXPOSE`, since you can't unexpose if the image artifact is used as a downstream image parent. The `-p` flag is the way to go, or you can put it in a Docker Compose configuration file instead if you wish (and start with `docker-compose` instead of `docker`).

Comment: @cbdeveloper If adding arguments to the run command is a hassle then your best bet is to use docker-compose. You could publish ports using your docker-compose.yaml. Another (not recommended) approach is setting your network mode to host using --net=host in cli or by configuring as such in the docker-compose.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Use host 0.0.0.0

```
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0' () => {
  console.log('Hello world listening on port', port);
});
```

Also, You need to publish port 3000:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 IMAGE_ID
```